# silverlight 3 datagrid drag-drop column vertically

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid, group-by

Is it possible to allow a datagrid column to be dragged vertically and dropped into an area above the datagrid which triggers it to group by that column?
If so, how would i best implement this into a silverlight 3 application?

Heres an example of what it could look like:
http://www.syncfusion.com/content/en-US/products/feature/windows-forms/grid/img/windows-forms-grid-dragcolumnintogrouparea.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, the Silverlight 3 DataGrid supports grouping internally (at an API level) but doesn't provide a UI to actually activate the grouping.  Dragging the column up above the normal headers is, as you say, an obvious way to do that, but it's just not implemented in the Silverlight 3 stock DataGrid.

Various other third party vendors (e.g. http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/gridview.aspx and http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/GridSilverlight/ and others...) do have nice Silverlight grids that provide this feature out of the box, as well as filtering, subgrids and all sorts of other bells & whistles. However, these are not free (but may be cheaper than implementing it yourself), and the company I work for evaluated many of these in June 2009 and found that the live scrolling performance was a bit poor compared to the (virtualising) built-in Silverlight DataGrid for large datasets.  Of course, things may now have changed, or you may care more about being able to group than scroll quickly.  Hope that helps?

Comment: I have been using telerik controls as an evaluation for the past month, and although most of their controls are great, their grid was rather slow in scrolling, enough to make me say "Not for now".